# How long to cook green onions relative to other vegetables

Tags: vegetables

I'm planning to put some green onions into my fried rice.

Normally when I make fried rice I'll brown some yellow onions in a big covered pan, add some slow cooking vegetables(Eg: carrots), leave that for a bit, add some quicker cooking vegetables(Eg: broccoli crowns), leave that for a bit, and then add the stuff that takes very little time to cook or is already cooked(Eg: Meat, rice, peas).

At what stage of this process should the green onions be added for best results?

Comment: I think this is largely based on preference. I'd finely chop the green onion and add it last after cooking everything and simply mix it in. The texture of the onion against everything that is cooked down should provide a pleasing contrast.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Looking at some recipes with green onions in indicated it shouldn't be hugely long, this was mostly a double check against the sort of disaster that would occur from putting the sorts of onions I'm more familiar with in at a very late stage.

Comment: Also consider that many people use scallion, green onion, and chive interchangeably when speaking; they are often confused. Green onion and scallions are very similar but chives are  more potent and you should avoid this technique with them. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically chop up the white and green parts of the green onion, and add them at different times during cooking:

I'll add the white part fairly early in the cooking.  (not as early as I would with bulb onions, as I cut the green onions more finely).  I want them to cook for a minute or two to take out the harshest flavors, but not cook too much.  I generally add them a minute or so before I add the rice to cook.

After I've cooked the rice for a bit, I'll add the green part.  This lets it soften up just a bit, but not really cook down.